# Arduino HMAC-SHA256 bearssl/bearssl_hmac.h

Tags: hmac, arduino-esp8266

I want to implement JWT for ESP8266 using the Arduino framework. I need as little dependencies as possible. So i wanted to use the "bearssl/bearssl_hmac.h" library, because this library is already included in the framework. The downside is, that it is not much documented.
What i got so far is inside the 'Sign' method that is invoked from inside the 'CreateToken' method, but the Serial Debug output is just rubbish like the following.
��)�몆~�j§��␚d�\���O�␞p�yJ␇�np���?p��?�␃��

```
    static void Sign(String payload, String secret, unsigned char buffer[32])
    {
        br_hmac_key_context keyCtx;
        br_hmac_key_init(&keyCtx, &br_sha256_vtable, secret.c_str(), secret.length());
        br_hmac_context hmacCtx;
        br_hmac_init(&hmacCtx, &keyCtx, 0);
        br_hmac_update(&hmacCtx, payload.c_str(), payload.length());
        br_hmac_out(&hmacCtx, buffer);
    }

    static void CreateToken(JsonObjectConst& jsonObj)
    {
        char json[256];
        serializeJson(jsonObj, json);
        // DebugPrintln(json);

        auto encodedPayload = Encode(json, 256);
        DebugPrintln(encodedPayload);
        
        char jsonWebToken[256];
        strcpy(jsonWebToken, HEADER);
        strcat(jsonWebToken, ".");
        strcat(jsonWebToken, encodedPayload);

        DebugPrintln(jsonWebToken);

        char* secret = "Test";
        unsigned char buffer[32];

        Sign(jsonWebToken, secret, buffer);

        DebugPrintln((char*)buffer);
    }
```

Can you give me any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this today for the same reasons you were.  You're getting the signature just fine I think (at least you're computing a SHA256 HMAC the same way I am).

Is `HEADER` base64 url encoded?
Also, does Encode base64 url encode json?

Once you have your signature bytes, you just need to base64 url encode them and append that to the end of your jsonWebToken.